# How to fix -table view header floating above table content-?

Tags: qml, tableview

i have a tableView in qml and i scroll the rows with a Slider. but the content of the table go underneath the header of the table
this is the table
i think it will work with detecting  the first row that in display first and set on itemDelegate visible on false,if currentRow is less that top + 2, but i don't know how to do this

```
TableView {
    id: tableView
    anchors.fill: tableImg
    backgroundVisible: false
    clip: true
    verticalScrollBarPolicy:   Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff;
    horizontalScrollBarPolicy: horizontalScrollBar;

    resources:
    {
        var length = columns.length
        var temp = []
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            temp.push(columnComponent.createObject(tableView, {"role": columns[i].role, "title": columns[i].title}));
        }

        return temp
    }

    model: scancardimg.model

    style: TableViewStyle {

        frame: Rectangle {
            color: "#00000000"
            border.color: "#00000000"
        }

        alternateBackgroundColor: "#00000000"

        headerDelegate: Rectangle {
            id: headerDelegate
            height: textItem.implicitHeight * 1.2 + scrMgr.size.height * 0.0277 //15
            width: textItem.implicitWidth
            color: "#00000000";

            Text {
                id: textItem
                anchors.fill: parent
                font.pixelSize: scrMgr.size.height * 0.028
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: styleData.textAlignment
                anchors.leftMargin: scrMgr.size.width * 0.0084 //8
                anchors.topMargin: scrMgr.size.height * 0.015 //8
                text: styleData.value
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJD91.png)

Comment: Just an observation on TableView vs ListView. Why is the ListView implementation so much better? I mean, on ListView, you have `header` and `headerPositioning` which would make the OP's problem trivia. Whereas in TableView we have to (1) work harder, (2) solve it differently.